# Custom Exceptions in Test method

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception

Why I can't catch custom exception in test classes?
If code throw custom exception, test immediatly fail.

System exceptions can be catched and handled in test methods without problems.

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
}
```

This exception have 30 level API

```
public class MyClass {
    public void methodToTest() {
        // do something
        someMethod();
    }

    @Future(callout = true)
    private static void someMethod() { 
        try {
            ...
            httpClient.send(httpRequest);
            ...
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // some actions
            throw new CustomException('<message>', ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This class also have 30 level API

In test class I have 2 mocks (for HttpCallout)

First throw my Custom Exception and second throw CalloutException

In first case test immediatly stop and fail on line

```
            httpClient.send(httpRequest);
```

In second case on line

```
            throw new CustomException('<message>', ex);
```

UPD. code:

```
public class MyClasss {

        public class CustomException extends Exception {
        }

        public void sendMethod() {
            String endPoint = 'endPoint';
            String body = 'body';
            send(endPoint, body);
        }

        @Future(callout=true)
        private static void send(String endPoint, String body) {
            try {
                 HttpRequest request =  new HttpRequest();
                request.setEndpoint('https://' + endPoint + '/');
                request.setMethod('POST');
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(Blob.valueOf(body).size()));
                request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                request.setBody(body);
                request.setTimeout(120000);

                new Http().send(request);
                System.assert(false);
            } catch (CustomException e) {
                throw e;
                System.assertEquals('error', e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CustomException('test', e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And test class

```
@IsTest
private class MyTest {



    private class Mock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        Boolean wasCalled = false;
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
            wasCalled = true;
            throw new MyClasss.CustomException('error');
        }
    }



    @IsTest
    static void test() {
        Mock m = new Mock();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, m);

        MyClasss instance = new MyClasss();
        Test.startTest();
        instance.sendMethod();
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(m.wasCalled);
    }
}
```

Comment: Best you post the relevant parts of your code - I have working tests that catch custom exceptions.

Comment: It's really strange, question will be updated in few minutes

Comment: When you say "stop and fail" what exactly does the test runner report?

Comment: Are you trying to test that the exception in your future method was thrown? If, I do not believe it will cause an exception that can be caught in your test as it is asynchronous after all. I could be wrong but outside of test it just prints the message in Alex jobs detail. The callout for api 30 will flat stop the test and never make it to an exception

Comment: In this case I think that all code between Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() inlined (and performed synchronously), but I am mistaken. Thank you, @Eric

Comment: @RasMisha - I just ran a test and the error from the Future method is catchable by the test method even though outside of the test there would be nothing to catch it

Comment: @Eric in my case test immediately failed, error: CustomException, and stack trace contains line where CustomException thrown.

Comment: @RasMisha - Yup that was what I was confirming. So if that is happening it your test case then what is your issue? Can you post up relevant part of your test cases and state why the error being thrown is not what you expected to happen as from what you have it seems that is exactly what is supposed to happen. Or are you saying that a custom exception thrown in the mock implementation is not caught in the future method by the custom exception catch. If the latter see the answer you already have and work through your code

Comment: @Eric "is not caught in the future method by the custom exception catch" this, you can see first case in stack trace I have only http.send line, not re-throw of CustomException in catch section.

Comment: @RasMisha - Review Keiths answer. I replicated it as well and it works properly on v30 API so there is something you are missing. At this point, your question does not provide enough info to reproduce the problem as we cannot see your test or the class where you are throwing the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44912/discussion-between-rasmisha-and-eric).

Comment: @Eric question has been updated

Comment: Why on hold? Code already added, you can see last update (and added before question marked "on hold"). I understand answer on easy questions more interesting for MVP (and recieve kilo-points), but intersting behaviour in salesforce more interesting for me, and I expect that someone can help and describe something (may be there are developers of apex here)

Answer (score 1):

This (updated to include the @future) test - where a custom exception is caught - passes including when using API 30:

```
@IsTest
private class MyTest {

    private class CustomException extends Exception {
    }

    private class Mock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        Boolean wasCalled = false;
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
            wasCalled = true;
            throw new CustomException('error');
        }
    }

    @Future(callout=true)
    private static void send() {
        try {
            new Http().send(new HttpRequest());
            System.assert(false);
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            System.assertEquals('error', e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @IsTest
    static void test() {
        Mock m = new Mock();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, m);
        Test.startTest();
        send();
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(m.wasCalled);
    }
}
```

Suggest you compare your logic with this to see what is different. Note that you must call `Test.stopTest()` to ensure that the @future call completes.

Comment: In dev.console I open and perform test. In tab Errors I have 'CustomException: <message>', in tab Stack Trace: MyClass.method: line 321, column 1 (where throw CustomException)
Caused by
Class.System.Type.newInstance: line 33, column 1

Comment: my fault, I use throw new CustomException('message', ex); in code

Comment: And one more detail :) This send method must be marked as @Future(callout = true), sorry

Comment: Question updated